# How to present very large amounts of Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI seems to choke up when trying to display several thousand lines of text

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text = Array(repeating: lipsum, count: 500).joined(separator: "")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // -[<_TtCOCV7SwiftUI11DisplayList11ViewUpdater8PlatformP33_65A81BD07F0108B0485D2E15DE104A7514CGDrawingLayer: 0x600000f65b60> display]:
            // Ignoring bogus layer size (361.000000, 209020.333333), contentsScale 3.000000, backing store size (1083.000000, 627061.000000)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(text)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

let lipsum = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi laoreet elementum purus.
Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec posuere congue facilisis.
Aenean sed neque purus. Integer ornare pretium condimentum.
Cras vel ipsum et risus vulputate auctor non ac ligula.
Morbi in sagittis sapien. Aliquam bibendum efficitur pellentesque.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque suscipit est sapien, id finibus quam sagittis at.
Duis augue quam, imperdiet ut erat quis, suscipit rutrum elit.
Pellentesque fringilla, nisi ut iaculis interdum, erat sapien auctor diam, nec eleifend orci massa ut neque.
Aenean accumsan, lorem eget finibus posuere, neque tortor hendrerit dui, sit amet tempus neque lectus at lorem.
Mauris convallis in nunc eget sollicitudin. Proin tincidunt diam ut vehicula feugiat.

"""
```

This never renders. And using a `UIViewRepresentable` with `UITextView` doesn't solve it either.

And by trial-and-error I found that the character limit is `151480`

Is this just yet-another-limitation of SwiftUI or is there a feasible workaround?

Comment: you could write the "text` into a `PDFDocument`, and use a `PDFView` to display
 it as a continous text or page by page.

Comment: Unfortunately my specific case needs tvOS support too, so that's not an option. But good suggestion for others, even if it requires a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with the same issue. By the way, the limit indicated in the question (151 488 characters) is not always the same: it depends on how many line breaks you have in the text, just to say an example. I managed to show more than 370 000 characters in some case, and couldn't see more than 120 000 in another.

The solution I found is to use `TextEditor` but blocking the edit, by replacing the `Binding` with a simple `.constant()`. This allows you to see it all and select the text too.

Here is how the example in the question would look like:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text = Array(repeating: lipsum, count: 500).joined(separator: "")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // -[<_TtCOCV7SwiftUI11DisplayList11ViewUpdater8PlatformP33_65A81BD07F0108B0485D2E15DE104A7514CGDrawingLayer: 0x600000f65b60> display]:
            // Ignoring bogus layer size (361.000000, 209020.333333), contentsScale 3.000000, backing store size (1083.000000, 627061.000000)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                Text("\(text.count) chars")

                TextEditor(text: .constant(text))   // <- This is the solution
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Mind that, the larger the text is, the longer it will take to load and scroll.

Comment: THANK YOU for this, especially for pasting the entire "_TtCOCV7SwiftUI11DisplayList11ViewUpdater8PlatformP33_65A81BD07F0108B0485D2E15DE104A7514CGDrawingLayer" into the comments. Not only does this solution fix the error and make this the ScrollView work for texts that exceed the unknowable limit, it also radically sped up the rendering for texts that did NOT exceed the limit and were "working" before.

It is annoying that, in iPadOS, to select a snippet from one of these 200,000+ character texts, you have to wait for it to auto-scroll to the bottom after you tap, and then scroll back up. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could just divide your text into chapters or paragraphs and use `LazyVStack` on them (even though it also works non-lazy):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let chapters = Array(repeating: lipsum, count: 500)

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(chapters.indices, id:\.self) { idx in
                    Text(chapters[idx])
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution breaks the text, so we can't select more than one "chapter". I wonder if there's a solution that maintains the whole text selectable, as a word processor does.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that makes assumptions about the text being possible to break up (as well as what HunterLion said). For example for presenting JSON it wouldn't really work :(